# Cake php modal validation error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a simple registration form and complete model validation.

```
public function add() {
            // Has any form data been POSTed?
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->User->set($this->request->data); //echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->data);exit;
                        if($this->User->validates()){
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    // Set a session flash message and redirect.
                    $this->Session->setFlash('User Saved!');
                    return $this->redirect('/users');
                }
}
            }
        }
```

Modal validation code is below

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
            ),
            'between' => array(
                'rule'    => array('between', 5, 15),
                'message' => 'Between 5 to 15 characters'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule'    => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'Minimum 8 characters long'
        ),
        'email' => 'email',
        'born' => array(
            'rule'       => 'date',
            'message'    => 'Enter a valid date',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    );
}
```

The problem is that when i delete html fields using firebug and submit form it save data with blank entries . i think its a big problem i am facing because it not good practice to save blank entry and i want to stop it by the hacker or any one. 
please help.

Comment: And where is your validation? You need to add validation rules in User model.

Comment: i added my modal code also but you not understanding my problem correctly. code working fine with html but if some user delete code using firebug then submit form then no validation error come and blank entries saved.

Comment: Check your mysql users table if its fields can be null or not.May be that is the problem.

Comment: @cakedev where you have validated it like `$this->Company->validates()` ?

Comment: @nedstark you not getting my point its not about table fields are null or not null. the problem is with validation.

Comment: Use [**`required`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required), `notEmpty` doesn't do what @semmelbroesel13 and @Er.KT think it does.

Comment: @ndm Thanks men you save my time . It works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the validation rule `'notEmpty'` for all fields which shouldn't be blank entries in the database.

Reference: [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3anotEmpty)

Comment: I have tried this already but this is not working and its obvious not working because my  question is about when some filed deleted by user for example email field are deleted by user using firebug and now he submit form on model validation there is check for email is valid or not . But this check is skip because email field is not in submitted form . and it skip that check and save data in DB. this not about only Email fields its about all fields and in any model. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with semmelbroesel13

please use **notEmpty** rules as:

**`'rule' => array('notempty')`**

**Updated:**

Please try below code and check whats the query exactly

```
public function add() {
            // Has any form data been POSTed?
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                  $this->User->set($this->request->data); //echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->data);exit;
                        if($this->User->validates()){
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
$log=$this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
 echo "<pre>";print_r($log);exit;
                    // Set a session flash message and redirect.
                    $this->Session->setFlash('User Saved!');
                    return $this->redirect('/users');
                }
}
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this already but this is not working and its obvious not working because my  question is about when some filed deleted by user for example email field are deleted by user using firebug and now he submit form on model validation there is check for email is valid or not . But this check is skip because email field is not in submitted form . and it skip that check and save data in DB. this not about only Email fields its about all fields and in any model. Please Help

Comment: so you can set in database not null

Comment: I have set already not null. Follow this link to see screenshot .http://i62.tinypic.com/o8bgo6.png

Comment: Check this below query------------ Array
(
    [log] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [query] => INSERT INTO `users` (`modified`, `created`) VALUES ('2014-05-01 18:23:09', '2014-05-01 18:23:09')
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [affected] => 1
                    [numRows] => 1
                    [took] => 1
                )

        )

    [count] => 1
    [time] => 1
)

Comment: have you tried to execute query INSERT INTO users (modified, created) VALUES ('2014-05-01 18:23:09', '2014-05-01 18:23:09') in phpmyadmin direct ?

Comment: yes it execute in mysql: check this screenshot     http://i60.tinypic.com/2a7927t.png

Comment: what happen any solution?

Comment: Yes, Use required, instead of notEmpty  @ndm solution  worked